# Moderator Pro Tem Announcement (the sequel)

Tags: discussion, moderators

I am pleased to announce that a member of our community has stepped up and generously volunteered his time to fill the gap I left when I went to work for Stack Exchange, making Parenting.SE just one of the sites I look after.

[image: Beofett]

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections in several weeks.**

Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

He will serve alongside the [existing pro tem moderators appointed in April](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154/moderator-pro-tem-announcement)

Comment: Congratulations Beofett! I'm sure that _Fanatic_ badge has nothing to do with your nomination?

Comment: Welcome to the team Beofett!

Answer (score 1):

A (**very**) belated "thank you!" to the community!  It's a pleasure and an honor to work with you all!