# Timeline of Parenting moderators

Tags: discussion, moderators

After the experimental [pro tem election](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1248/2018-community-moderator-election-results) I noticed that, unlike on some other SE sites, the 
[Moderator Pro Tem Announcement](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154/moderator-pro-tem-announcement) has never been edited to reflect moderator changes. This self-answered Q&A is an attempt to piece together the history of Parenting moderators; edits are welcome.

Answer (score 6):

#### Timeline of Parenting moderators

2011-04-27: [cabbey, HedgeMage, and Torben Gundtofte-Bruun are appointed](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154/moderator-pro-tem-announcement)

2011-07-19: [HedgeMage became a Stack Exchange employee, Beofett is appointed](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204/moderator-pro-tem-announcement-the-sequel?noredirect=1)

2013-12-13: [cabbey and Torben Gundtofte-Bruun step down](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/580/thank-you-torben-and-cabbey)

2014-01-06: [balanced mama and Karl Bielefeldt are appointed](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/604/please-welcome-your-new-moderators-balanced-mama-and-karl-bielefeldt)

2014-10-09: [balanced mama steps down](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/705/parenting-stack-exchange-has-an-opening-for-a-moderator-are-you-interested)

2015-02-18: [anongoodnurse and Rory Alsop are appointed, Beofett steps down](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/705/3)

2015-04-17: [Erica is appointed](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/802/please-welcome-a-new-moderator-erica)

2015-04-18: [Karl Bielefeldt steps down](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/804/stepping-down-as-moderator)

2018-05-15: [Joe is elected, Erica steps down](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1248/2018-community-moderator-election-results)

2020-01-23: [anongoodnurse steps down](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1371/the-time-has-come-for-me-to-resign)

2020-06-09: [First election after graduation.  Rory Alsop, SomeShinyObject and Stephie are elected. Joe didn’t chose to run and leaves the moderator team.](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1407/2020-community-moderator-election-results)

#### Details that remain unclear

- [Moderator page](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) says that anongoodnurse was appointed 2015-12-08, not 2015-02-18.

Comment: @Joe you can see when a moderator was appointed by checking their info from the mod profile. By the way, nice post! I copied the idea into Spanish.SE -> [Histórico de moderadores de Spanish.SE / Timeline of Spanish.SE moderators](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3186/1674) and added the flair to each one of the moderators on every moment.