# Should the title of a merged question indicate that it was merged?

Tags: discussion, editing, questions

Both questions have been merged into another one:

- [How do you get a toddler to brush her teeth?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/1239/how-do-you-get-a-toddler-to-brush-her-teeth)
- [At what age get a child to stop using pullups at night? [merged]](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/1546/at-what-age-get-a-child-to-stop-using-pullups-at-night-merged)

Actually, the 2nd question is the only example I found of a merged question with a modified title, yet it was edited by a [moderator](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1252/30519). There doesn't seem to have been a meta discussion yet.

While merged questions are rare, I do think that modifying the title like this is maybe a good idea. [Merged questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158067/377968) are special:

- "All of the merged question's answers, including their votes and comments, become answers to the target question."
- "The merge stub question is locked to prevent edits to its content that would make the merge no longer make sense."

But there is no indication that a question is merged until you actually click on it. It just looks like a regular question with no answers.

**Should the title be edited to include [merged] (or something else) or not?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On this site, we don't have that many - a merge requires the two to be very similar, and usually we spot the dupe before many answers are posted. I think for that one there was discussion between mods to ensure the new question made sense, but I don't think there is policy on this.

Having MERGED in there is not necessary, though - it is irrelevant to any future readers.

Comment: I tracked down a [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/51498/377968) that didn't get too far, though (but people seemed to like it). Does [merged] contain less info for future readers than [closed] or [duplicate]? Or is this just because there are generally so few merged questions (in contrast to closed / duplicate ones)?

Comment: It's just that it oesn't matter if it is merged - it doesn't change the question or answer (as we can only merge if they are basically identical)