# 2020 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Parenting’s [second moderator election](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the three new moderators are:

[image: Rory Alsop] [image: SomeShinyObject] [image: Stephie]

They'll be your first elected moderators since you lost your "beta" label last year—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Let's also take a moment to thank [the previous team who've served you as pro-tems](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1251/timeline-of-parenting-moderators) while your site was still in beta.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/election/2), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5681179397193728/0).

Answer (score 6):

Congratulations Rory/SomeShinyObject/Stephie, I know I've left the site in good hands!

I appreciate everything that everyone did to help moderate the site, especially while it was just me for the last few months of last year actively moderating.  It was great having community members who actively flagged content so I didn't tend to have to hunt for problems - they were usually there in the flag queue waiting for me to deal with.  We have a great community, and I'm proud to be a part of it.